# SQL Agent Jobs - What Permissions Required

Tags: sql-server-agent

We have a application that allows a user to view a list of SQL Agent jobs and create new ones.

However, the application displays a form asking for user credentials.
The user is a member of the **SQLAgentOperatorRole** in **msdb**.

I tested by making the user a member of **sysadmin** and this works.

Obviously I do not want to make that user sysadmin so what permission level am I missing?

Comment: What is the application doing?  Is this a SQL Server login or a Windows login? Does your application create a new SQL Agent proxy account? Et cetera.  More details would help.

Answer (score 2):

`SQLAgentUserRole` allows users to create jobs and to manage jobs that they create.

The `SQLAgentOperatorRole` allows users all the rights assigned to the `SQLAgentReaderRole` along with the permissions necessary to execute local jobs that they do not own.

Member of `SQLAgentReaderRole` role allow the user to see any SQL Agent job located on the server instance, even the jobs in which that user does not own. The user can see the job, along with any history saved to the job. However, the group is not allowed to execute the jobs

Comment: Yes. I had all that. The user is a member of SQLAgentOperatorRole. But I am obviously missing some other permission.

Comment: Still no solution on this. The Job actually calls an SSIS package so could it be something with that?

Answer (score 0):

if the user is not member of sysadmin role then proxy account needs to be used

Comment: Could you expand on this answer please?